# Erro 500 ao acessar a página edit, ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails

tenho uma aplicação em rails que logo após carregar a página edit.html.haml renderizando o layout me retorna um erro 500, a tabela no BD possui apenas um registro e está vinculado à outra tabela(sistema de credenciais/autorização), estou rodando a aplicação numa VM em modo bridge no linux mint 17 rebecca

edit 1
segue o output do console logo após o carregamento dos roles:

```
Started GET "/clients/new" for 192.168.1.161 at 2015-03-12 18:28:23 -0300
Processing by ClientsController#new as HTML
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2   LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_request_at` = '2015-03-12 21:28:23',    `perishable_token` = 'zJ6WIgsox0VkSEzRwGlr', `updated_at` = '2015-03-12 21:28:23' WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
(1.4ms)  COMMIT
Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE `roles_users`.`user_id` = 2 AND `roles`.`name` = 'admin' LIMIT 1
Rendered clients/_form.html.haml (5.9ms)
Rendered clients/new.html.haml within layouts/application (7.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms
```

Comment: Rendered clients/_form.html.haml (3.3ms)
  Rendered clients/new.html.haml within layouts/application (3.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms

Comment: Não tem mais nada no console?

Comment: tem algumas queries de mysql para checar usuário, mas são exatamente as mesmas para qualquer outra página, e só aparece isso quando pede o "_form"(página new.erb.html também dá este problema).

Comment: Poste o seu log na pergunta.

Comment: editado com o log

Comment: O log do console e completo, ai não dá pra ver qual o erro.

Comment: exato! após as querys de mysql (que são umas 4 para a checagem da autenticação) isso é TUDO que aparece. verifiquei a as tabelas de users e roles e a roles_users mas não há nenhum registro faltando, nenhuma junção que não exista...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

desculpem o transtorno, neste caso em específico, devido a algum motivo mina tela de debug não estar funcionando corretamente não conseguia diagnosticar que, o problema era o método de rota "_path()", grato pela atenção de todos.

Answer (score 0):

Não vai ser possível ajudar você sem saber exatamente qual o erro no código. Parece que você está rodando o servidor em modo produção para não aparecer o debug na página.

Sugiro rodar o servidor em modo dev e publicar o erro que deu.

Para isso rode: rails server RAILS_ENV=development

Comment: pois é, mas quando eu mando ele exibir o ENV ele retorna "development"

Comment: Entento. Nesse caso cole o erro que esta dando para podermos saber melhor...

Comment: erro colado na pergunta

Comment: Olá André. Não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro ali. Não tem como você colocar um print da tela com o nome do erro? Ele deve aparecer na tela se você estiver rodando em desenvolvimento

Comment: pois é, aparece apenas a tela "we're sorry, but something went wrong"

Comment: Pois é. Como eu havia dito você está rodando em ambiente de produção, por isso o erro não aparece. Você está rodando na sua própria máquina ou em outro lugar? Se for na sua máquina, você deve rodar em modo de desenvolvimento, assim você vai ver os erros assim que eles acontecerem...

Comment: Tente rodar esse comando (pode copiar e colar): 

rails server RAILS_ENV=development

Comment: não estou rodando em ambiente produção pois quando eu mando printar o env ele retorna "development".